# Running QtWebEngine with C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtwebengine

I'm trying out Qt for the first time and want to create a very basic application which loads a website. I want to use Qt WebEngine.

This is my helloworld.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = hello
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

QT += webenginewidgets

SOURCES += hello.cpp
```

And this is my hello.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(parent);
    view->load(QUrl("http://qt-project.org/"));
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

When trying to compile I get the error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: QWebEngineView
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets
```

I guess I know that it cannot find the modules, but looking into the qt-documentation it seems as the right way to include them.

I'm running QtCreator 3.4.2 on Qt 5.5.0.

Comment: Do you have the qtwebengine modules installed? This can be done either via the MaintenanceTool, or if you're running linux, you need to install the webengine packages.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it is only supported on a few compilers right now:

http://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine#Q:_On_which_platforms_will_it_run.3F

Try building with one of those configured, and it should work.

My guess is that basically the Chromium project it is built on is very complex with lots of dependencies and QtWebEngine hasn't been backported other compilers yet.

QtWebKit should still be supported most of the time, but QtWebEngine is where things are headed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Webkit package installation can resolve the issue:
[apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev]

Comment: Could you please provide more details? How to install the webkit package? Where should I type `apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev`?

Comment: In terminal console first type [sudo su ] then apt-get install command. What OS you are using?

Comment: I'm using Mac on a virtual machine and I tried to do that and it said "command not found" when I tried to do `apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev`.

Comment: I'm working on linux but presume that for MacOS you should check out installer [ man installer ]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to compile the Qt's [WebEngine Widgets Minimal Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webengine-minimal-example.html)
using mingw compiler and it failed to compile, but when I tried  to compile it with MSVC2017_64bit, it successfully compiled.
I am using version of Qt 5.14.2 and from the information bout the QTWebEngine module in the maintenance tool you will find the following:
[image]