# QT: QTWebview is not working

Tags: c++, qt, webview, webkit

My operating System: Windows 7 64bit

QT Version: QT Creator 4.2.0 based on QT 5.7.1(MSVC 2015, 32 bit)

The QWebview widget is not displayed in my mainwindow.ui file.

I already tried following steps:

```
-QT += webkitwidgets or QT+= webenginewidgets
-include <QTWebView> or include <QTWebEngineView>
```

After using the above commands i got this project error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets
```

I also tried to reinstall the QT Creator, but i still got the same problem, i cant use any web-related widgets(Webkit/WebEngineView, ...).
Thanks for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: See [Running QtWebEngine with C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722997/running-qtwebengine-with-c)

Comment: @VladimirBershov I tried the 5.6.2 and 5.7.1 debugger, but its still not working, under the link i found that page http://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine#Q:_On_which_platforms_will_it_run.3F It says "On which platforms will it run" but there is no information about the right debugger. I just found this page in the qt wiki, but smb. deleted the topic... http://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngineOnWindows